LaTeX Symbol Spacing Issues
I am writing a research paper using LaTeX, and under my Acknowledgments section I would like to mention that the document was created using LaTeX. When I compile it and run the code, the LaTeX symbol 'sticks' to the next word, despite me putting a space there. Any help?
This document was compiled using \LaTeX in Overleaf.
When it is compiled, it becomes: "This document was compiled using LaTeXin Overleaf." Any advice to make this work?

Try closing the argument with a pair of curly braces: \LaTeX{} in Overleaf.

@barbarabeeton ;)
